# Проблема в добавление папки в другую папку в Appdata\Roaming

Tags: c#

Я делаю программу которая будет закачивать файлы и добавлять их в `AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\resourcepacks`

Хоть я и дал права администратора, программа не дает мне сохранять туда файлы

Вот мой код:
'''

```
string outputPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), @".minecraft\resourcepacks\");'''
```

update

```
    private async void guna2Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string fileUrl = "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B5SRNdXkX0ibU3JXa0k0Z3M4bFE?resourcekey=0-TV2Jjli-58cRQljzmJhomQ";
            string outputPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), @".minecraft\resourcepacks\");


            await DownloadFileFromGoogleDrive(fileUrl, outputPath);
        }

        private static async Task DownloadFileFromGoogleDrive(string fileUrl, string outputPath)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(fileUrl);
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(outputPath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await stream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Как вы получили строку с путём не особо важно, хотя и следует проверить, действительно ли путь правильный в ней. Главное нет кода, который занимается самим копированием и текст ошибки. Текст ошибка в большинстве содержит описание того, где возникла проблема и почему.

Comment: Хотяб ошибку написали с какой падает... Может вам пишет "такой директории нет", а вы нам о права говорите, может ведь такое быть? Может. Ну так пожалуйста, все данные в вопрос, включая ошибку, результат приложенного кода, а также сам код "закачивания файла". Без этого ответить на ваш вопрос == гадание на кофейной гуще.

Comment: Прошу прощение за путаницу

Comment: Я изменил вопрос

Comment: Ошибка у вас `DirectoryNotFoundException: "Could not find a part of the path ..."` - и вот что тут не понятного? Вот я вижу вы создаете файл, ок, а папку вы создаете? Нет... Далее, вот у вас в `outputPath` лежит допустим `C:/Path/To/Directory`, вы ее указали, ок, но... Где название файла? Перед `HttpClient` напишите `Directory.CreateDirectory(outputPath);`, а `FileStream(outputPath` поменяйте на `FileStream(Path.Combine(outputPath, "Super.file")`. Ну и да, `HttpClient` создается **только раз** на все время работы приложения, а не каждый вызов метода.

Comment: Нет, ошибка не в этом, а в  Access dines]

Comment: И я не создаю файл, а скачиваю из интернета, и помещаю в папку майнкрафта и далее ресурс паки, у вас ее нету наверное

Comment: `new FileStream(outputPath, FileMode.Create)` - создать файл по указанному пути и открыть его поток для записи... Еще раз говорю, вы обязаны создавать папку перед тем, как записываете, а также вы обязаны указывать **ИМЯ** создаваемого файла, а не просто путь к папке.

Comment: Так зачем указывать имя, если я просто скачиваю архив из интернат а далее распаковываю  его в другу. папку, лол, название уже есть, ибо тогда мне ваще пришлось париться чтобы он читал название с сайта гугл драйва и давал его папке

Comment: И зачем создавать папку, если она уже там есть, у меня будет просто 2 одинаковых папки

Comment: ChatGPT наверное правильно написал

Comment: либо же покажите правильный код, я плюс на ютубе смотрел еще

Comment: FileStream file = new FileStream(@"C:\newfil.html", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

Comment: Я пофиксил ошибку